# OpenMP: conditional use of #pragma

Tags: c++, openmp, pragma

I'm using OpenMP to improve my program efficiency on loops.

But recently I discovered that on small loops the use of this library decreased performances and that using the normal way was better.

In fact, I'd like to use openMP only if a condition is satisfied, my code is

```
#pragma omp parallel for
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   do_some_stuff ();
```

But what I want to do is to disable the #pragma if *size* is  small enough i.e.:

```
if (size > OMP_MIN_VALUE)
  #pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
do_some_stuff ();
```

But does not work, the better way is to write the loop twice but I don't want to do that way...

```
if (size > OMP_MIN_VALUE)
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    do_some_stuff ();
}
else
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    do_some_stuff ();
}
```

What is the better way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve the effect you're looking for by using the optional [`schedule` clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses) on your `parallel for` directive:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, OMP_MIN_VALUE)
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   do_some_stuff ();
```

You might want to play around with different kinds of scheduling though and different chunk sizes to see what suits your library routines best.

Comment: I used #pragma omp parallel for if (size >= OMP_MIN_VALUE)